# Text based game inventory system issues

Tags: java

```
  System.out.println ("The door slowly sides open and reveals a golden sword, enter 1 to pick it up");
  String pickupsword = scanner.next();
  p.addItemToInv("Golden Sword");
```

This is calling from the player class I made

```
public class Player {

public void addItemToInv(String name){
    for (int i = 0; 1 < inv.length; i++){
        if (inv[i] == null)
        {
            inv[i] = name;
            System.out.println ("you have added" + name + " .");
            return;
        }
    }
    System.out.println ("You have no room in your inventory");
}
private static String inv [] = new String [5];
}
```

And now I'm stumped, lets say that I wanted the user to actually USE the sword, I would have to build an inventory system right?

Comment: It's not clear what you're actually asking here... Yes, if you want your program to do something, you'll have to write the code to do it. Note that `1 < inv.length` is always going to be true, and you're currently making the player pick up the sword whether they press 1 or not.

Comment: I'm sorry its late and my message was muddled. What I'm asking is essentially help moving forward, sorry again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The textual system is a really bad choice if you want him to use the sword or other things like armors, shields and so on. 
You could make several classes like Weapon, Armor and shield:

```
public class Weapon {
    private int damage;
    private int durability;

    public class Weapon(int damage, int durability) {
        this.damage = damage;
        this.durability = durability;
    }
}
```

Now your golden sword can implement the Weapon class. You can add methods and maybe the name to this Weapon class and have the "golden sword" class implement these methods. After this you add some variables to your player like Weapon, Armor, Shield. If he picks up a weapon you can say:

```
player.setWeapon(goldenWeapon);
```

This is the better approach in the long run.